# Vowpal Wabbitを使ったContextual Banditでの予測確立の出力の制御方法

Tags: python, 機械学習

Vowpal Wabbitを使って、以下のような仕様でContextual Banditの実装を試しました。

- アクションは5種類：Lv1, Lv2, Lv3, Lv4 ,Lv5
- 学習データは600行程度
- 実行環境はPython3.10

学習データとして以下のサンプル"learn_example"を用意したとします。

```
learn_example = (
"Lv2:7.69:0.2 | A:7.58 B:20.4 C:56.41 D:4",  # <action:cost:probability | features> 
"Lv2:20.6:0.2 | A:3.18 B:21.3 C:56.41 D:4",
"Lv1:11.8:0.3 | A:24.19 B:22.8 C:52.41 D:5",
"Lv3:38.9:0.2 | A:33.27 B:24.1 C:53.41 D:5",
"Lv5:8.95:0.1 | A:56.48 B:24.4 C:48.35 D:5",
"Lv1:35.9:0.2 | A:46.21 B:25.6 C:49.85 D:5",
"Lv4:0.69:0.1 | A:25.81 B:22.4 C:50.21 D:5",
"Lv3:15.7:0.2 | A:13.33 B:21.2 C:51.71 D:5",
....
)
```

この学習データを利用して以下のようなコードで予測を実行しました。

```
vw = vowpalwabbit.Workspace("--cb_explore 5 --epsilon 0.25 --cb_type dr") 

for example_data in learn_example:
    vw.learn(example_data)

sample_context = "| A:18.36 B:20.1 C:49.23 D:5"

predict_result = vw.predict(sample_context)
print(predict_result)
```

実行結果は以下の通りになりました。

```
[0.20761550962924957, 0.1931363344192505, 0.19554626941680908, 0.19322560727596283, 0.21047623455524445]
```

私の理解では、学習データに投入されたアクションの順番に予測確立が示されるという理解のため、以下のように対応づいていると考えています。

```
[Lv2:0.20761550962924957, Lv1:0.1931363344192505, Lv3:0.19554626941680908, Lv5:0.19322560727596283, Lv4:0.21047623455524445]
```

この予測結果を制御し、表示される予測結果を制御したいのですが、その方法について教えてください。

```
[Lv1:0.1931363344192505,　Lv2:0.20761550962924957, Lv3:0.19554626941680908, Lv4:0.21047623455524445, Lv5:0.19322560727596283]
```